# Bean could not be found when running Spring Boot application in STS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I get this when I try to run my Spring Boot application in STS:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.greglturnquist.learningspringboot2.learningspringboot2.ImageService required a bean of type 'com.greglturnquist.learningspringboot2.learningspringboot2.ImageRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.greglturnquist.learningspringboot2.learningspringboot2.ImageRepository' in your configuration.
```

I tried adding

```
compile ("com.greglturnquist.learningspringboot2.learningspringboot2.ImageRepository")
```

to `build.gradle` but that's made no difference. How do I resolve this?

This is my ImageRepository class:

```java
package com.greglturnquist.learningspringboot2.learningspringboot2;

import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public interface ImageRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Image, String> {

    Mono<Image> findByName(String name);

}
```

Comment: It can't find ImageRepository bean, can you show how did you write ImageRepository class or interface so that can help better.

Comment: @P3arl I've added it to the question.

Comment: Please try which I just answered below.

Comment: Hmmm, that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you included repositories in your component scan? and you are getting the same exception now?

Answer (score 1):

Please add @Repository to your class and run.

```
@Repository
public interface ImageRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Image, String> {

    Mono<Image> findByName(String name);

}
```

**Update:**
And also include @EnableJpaRepositories above your configuration or SpringBootApplication class to include those in component scan.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add @Repository anotation to you class.

```
@Repository
public interface ImageRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Image, String> {

}
```

Kindly add it and hopefully it will solve your problem.